# <ul> tag image list exceeds borders when float right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add some animations on image list using this javascript:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#rotate1').innerfade({
                animationtype: 'slide',
                speed: 750,
                timeout: 4000,
                type: 'sequence',
                containerheight: 'auto'
            });
        });
</script>
```

Here is my html code where I'm using `<ul>` tag image list to for the animation:

```
<div style="text-align:right; vertical-align: top; float: right; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px">
    <ul id="rotate1" style="list-style: none; width: 100%">
        <li><img src="~/Images/logo11w.png" alt="1" style="border:8px solid #d6d6d6;">first image text</li>
        <li><img src="~/Images/movies1.png" alt="1" style="border:8px solid #d6d6d6;">first image text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I set the id `id="rotate1"` on the `<ul>` the image list goes out of the border of my page since while float is right. When I don't set `id="rotate1"` it stays in the border of my page even when float right is set.

If there's only one image in `<ul>` tag then image stays in borers.
If float right is removed from styles, image stays in borders.

image below is how I want it to be
[image: example image]

and this is how it is using `id="rotate1"`
[image: example image]

edit: created a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/naveedshr/7t7csaz0/

Comment: What about making a fiddle???

Comment: You should also let the text float right. Just take a look at this http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/ht/wrap_text_image.htm tutorial. You should be able to use the same technique for your ul element.

Comment: it works perfectly when im adding images without using the script id. like in image1 in question, images were added using ul tag but when i set id=rotate it goes out of page borders.

Comment: here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/naveedshr/7t7csaz0/
sorry if there's any incovenience, i first time created a fiddle. javascript code was a include file i couldn't upload so copied all file in javascript section. the very last function is main. rest is its definition i think. dont know much about javascript.

try to remove id="rotate1" it will be set in the main area where it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe the problem with your text. It is not adjusting with your image. The image is set float and the text goes at the back. The image will come in front of text. So, use div for the text and try to set the text also to float - left, right wherever you want.

And for the image, I would recommend using `position: absolute` instead of float and then specify left and right.

```
<div style="text-align:right; vertical-align: top; position:absolute; left:100; right: 100">
<!--All the other code here-->
</div>
```

I hope it works perfectly!

Comment: i had removed all the text to see if it's not adjusting with text. but but it's same as the second image in question without a single word present. all blank white page with image location right to the screen. also, absolute position makes image render over the text.

Comment: No, you have got it wrong. I said, your text will come the same way  if you want to float. Your image can come at the place where you want. But the text will remain as it is. So, to align text as shown in the first picture, I advised to put it in div. And for the image, I will just see.

Comment: i created a fiddle can you take a look at this please?
http://jsfiddle.net/naveedshr/7t7csaz0/
 images has to be in main (white) area. which i get when remove id="rotate1"